# Die roller using python

Tags: python

So I have been putting together a small text based game and I was wondering if this was the best way to execute a die roller:

```
import random

def roll_die(die_type, roll_times, print_op):
    total_roll = 0
    for roll_times:
        roll_result = random.randint(1, die_type)
        roll_result += total_roll
        if print_op == True:
            print(roll_result)
            print(total_roll)
```

I haven't done to much in python so if this is horrible beyond comprehension I understand.

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: It certainly isn't the best way, as it isn't a way at all; `for roll_times:` is a `SyntaxError`, which you should probably have mentioned somewhere.

Comment: If you want a review of your finished code, *after you have finished testing it to ensure that it works* (spoiler alert: it doesn't, yet), try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: follow this tutorial, it should help you, http://christopherhacking.co.uk/2013/12/18/rolling-a-die-in-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good time to get to grips with splitting things into small, self-contained functions and passing arguments around. As I see it, you have *two* tasks here:

1. Roll a single die once; and
2. Sum total of multiple rolls.

So this should be two functions:

```
import random

def roll_die(die_type, print_op=False):
    roll_result = random.randint(1, die_type)
    if print_op:
        print("Roll: {0}.".format(roll_result))
    return roll_result

def roll_dice(die_type, roll_times, print_op=False):
    total_roll = 0
    for _ in range(roll_times):
        total_roll += roll_die(die_type, print_op)
        if print_op:
            print("Running total: {0}.".format(total_roll))
    return total_roll
```

In use:

```
>>> print("Output: {0}.".format(roll_dice(6, 3, True)))
Roll: 5.
Running total: 5.
Roll: 1.
Running total: 6.
Roll: 5.
Running total: 11.
Output: 11.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do if I were you, adapting your code to something that works and seems to do what you want:

```
import random

def roll_die(die_type, roll_times, print_op=False):
    total_roll = 0              # you need to use an iterable to iterate over
    for _ in range(roll_times): # range is made for this
        roll_result = random.randint(1, die_type)
        total_roll += roll_result # you mixed these up
        if print_op:
            print(roll_result)
    if print_op:
        print(total_roll)
    return total_roll # don't forget to return your result
```

And demo of usage:

```
>>> print('returning:', roll_die(6, 3, True))
1
6
5
12
('returning:', 12)
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help a lot.

Comment: `if print_op == True` can be simplified as just `if print_op:` ... using == for a True comparison is sort of against Python styles anyway. Worst case you could say `is True` instead of `== True`, but since it's already holding the boolean value, no comparison is needed at all.

Comment: @iandouglas see [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations); "Yes: `if greeting:`, No:    `if greeting == True:`, Worse: `if greeting is True:`"