# Python: Random seed issues

Tags: python, random

I know that a random number from any computer is not truly random, however I would expect a little more variation than what I'm currently getting. I'm trying to simulate dice rolls, for example 4d6 would be four rolls of a 6-sided die. This is much more accurate than simply generating a random number between 4 and 24 (I won't get into the probability curve here.)

What I'm finding is that seeding off of the current system time (which I always felt was as good as any seed, could be wrong) was that the numbers are consistently low. I mean after about 50 rolls of 3d6, I've never once gotten a sum of above 12. That's a 0 hit rate of the top 1/3rd of the range, which I think is particularly odd.

Here's some code, hopefully someone knows of a better way to do this, perhaps seeding from system time is inherently bad and I just have no idea:
(I omitted the non-pertinent class definitions)

```
from random import randrange, seed

def dieroll(self,numrolls,dierange):
    """ This method will return 'num' rolls of a d'range' die. 
    For example, 4d6 will simulate four rolls of a 6-sided die. """

    seed()
    sum = 0
    for roll in range(0, numrolls):
        dieroll = randrange(1,dierange)
        sum = sum + dieroll
    print("Sum = %d" % sum)
```

Here is a small sample of my results:

```
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 3 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 11 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 9 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 9 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 10 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 11 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 7 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 7 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 11 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 11 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 4 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 11 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 6 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 12 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 6 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 8 
>>> c.dieroll(3,6) 
Sum = 8
```

I'd expect a bell curve of values, and though this small sample set (I wasn't going to post the whole 50 results) my overall results is highly skewed on the low side.

Thanks for any help on this -- I'd like these results to be as realistic as "real dice" as possible!

Edit: After about 20 more rolls, I did manage to get a 13 and a 14, so I know it's possible. I had about 10 under 6, though.

2nd Edit: I just realized that dierange should be dierange + 1 -- 1d6 was consistently returning results from 1-5... still not sure that the seed is as accurate as it can be.

Comment: Why are you seeding at all? I generally only seed the RNG when I'm testing, to ensure deterministic outputs. Also, you aren't using any instance attributes - consider making this a `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Maybe it's been a while, but I thought you always had to seed when generating a random number... is that not the case? This is my first RNG in python, I admit.

Comment: This is very weird. However, you can try using `(random.randint(1,50000) % dierange )+1` instead of `randrange(1,dierange)` (your code is nicer, but just to check if the problem consist)

Comment: It is automatically seeded with system time when imported - unless you specifically want to reset it, you can leave it alone. In terms of the rest of your implementation, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24711018/3001761) useful.

Comment: The upper end of the range is a big problem, but seeding is a more subtle one. If you're going to seed the RNG rather than using the default, do so once and only once per run.  You're re-seeding it for each invocation, which can definitely lead to non-random results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`randrange`, like `range`, doesn't include its upper bound.

Your die doesn't have a 6..

Compare `randint`, which *does* include the upper bound.

Comment: Thanks DSM, I realized that just before you posted, that was it! I updated the code and now it's generating more expected results that match real dice. Thanks! (I'll mark as answered when the time limit expires.)  I spent too much time thinking it was a seed issue rather than verifying the code was correct.

Comment: @TimS.: you might be interested in `collections.Counter`.  If you modify your function to return a value, you could write something like `Counter(c.dieroll(3, 6) for i in range(10**6)) and get a nice distribution.  [PS: it's a bad habit to shadow the built-in function `sum` with a variable of your own.]

Comment: Thanks, I normally create longer variables so they don't interfere with built-ins, but just threw this together. I'll definitely update the code, thanks for the catch. The Counter looks pretty nice, I'll try that out too. Appreciate the help!